# Web Animations API - varying animation durations?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm experimenting with the Web Animations API which currently works only in Webkit browsers. As one can imagine, the documentation is a bit sparse:

- [Here's a blog post I found on it](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36)
- [Here's the spec](http://w3c.github.io/web-animations/)

I'm trying to do two things:

- Reverse the animation at a random point in time before the animation ends.
- Stagger the duration of the effects in the animation. For example, for a 3 second animation, the first portion of it should be 1.25s and the second portion should be 1.75s.

Here's a working example which uses the Web Animation API. My concern is that the 3 animations are spaced evenly among the 3 seconds. How can I space them out differently without instantiating multiple animationPlayer objects?

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  var animationPlayer = this.animate([{
    transform: 'translateX(0px)'
  }, {
    transform: 'translateX(600px)'
  }, {
    transform: 'translate(600px, 200px)'
  }], 3000);

  animationPlayer.onfinish = function(e) {
    console.log('complete!');
  }

  //  wiggle wiggle wiggle
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationPlayer.reverse();
    setTimeout(function() {
      animationPlayer.reverse();
    }, 250);
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question, looks like Chrome implementation still hasn't the reverse function. This is consistent with the documentation that you have linked. May be in Canary, but I haven't checked.

Correction: reading an update in your linked blog, looks like it has been added to Chrome. However, it isn't working for me ...

About your second question, specify an offset in your second keyframe

If the first transform must run for 1.25 s, for a total of 3 s, this is 1.25 / 3 = .416, so

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  var animationPlayer = this.animate([{
    transform: 'translateX(0px)'
  }, {
    transform: 'translateX(600px)', offset: 0.416
  }, {
    transform: 'translate(600px, 200px)'
  }], 3000);

  animationPlayer.onfinish = function(e) {
    console.log('complete!');
  }

  //  wiggle wiggle wiggle
  setTimeout(function() {
    animationPlayer.reverse();
    setTimeout(function() {
      animationPlayer.reverse();
    }, 250);
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail on offset usage? I can see it affecting the durations of my transitions, but I don't appear to be able to use multiple offsets. When I try to apply two offsets to two transforms I get an error, "Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported."

Comment: May be are you trying to set offsets on the first or last value ? It should work only on the intermediate values.