# Reverse a CSS animation which is in progress

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a box which turns blues and then fades to green when clicked.
I would like the box to reverse its fade direction and go from blue-green back to blue if it is clicked again before it completes its first animation.

I want to avoid using transitions* because when replacing a keyframe with multiple transitions* there is a delay between each as the browser needs a second to acknowledge the new CSS class.

You can see what I mean by this delay in this more complex example:

- Delay because of appending class: http://codepen.io/Meo/pen/QwERrR
- No delay because of animation: http://codepen.io/Meo/pen/RNGwPe

Is this possible? My attempt is below, but it does not work as hoped.

Also, I've [looked into using the Web Animations API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597168/web-animations-api-varying-animation-durations) but it's pretty new and seems to have its own set of limitations although it can reverse an animation.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('colored')) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('reverse')) {
      $(this).removeClass('reverse');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('reverse').removeClass('colored');
    }
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('colored');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.colored {
  -webkit-animation: color 4s linear forwards;
}
.reverse {
  -webkit-animation: color 4s linear backwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: CSS Transitions may be a way easier way of doing this.

Comment: As stated in the problem description - I would like to avoid using transforms (Oh, I said transforms in the description, I meant transitions. Sorry, it's early) rather than animations. When listening to 'webkitTransitionEnd' and then applying a new CSS class to simulate steps in the keyframe there is a delay between each step because the browser needs a moment to acknowledge the new CSS class on the element. This leaves the overall effect feeling clunky rather than smooth.

Comment: I know the Greensock library can reverse animations using JS – I'm not sure if its overkill for what you are trying to do though! Maybe it will help: http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/AwCKp

Comment: I forgot about Greensock! It might be overkill, but it's certainly worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be accomplished without clunkiness or delay (or even multiple lines of JS logic like you've got above), assuming it's just changing simple CSS properties like background color.

Does this pen accomplish the effect you're going for? It just uses the jQuery toggleClass method to switch between the two CSS states of the box. And, just using the simpler CSS transition and not bothering with keyframes and all that business, it should animate without delay or stuttering just fine and be able to go back and forth at any point in the animation:

*UPDATE*
I edited mine to recreate what I think is the effect you were going for - is this closer to what you were wanting the animation to look like (minus easing and length of animation, I mean)?

http://codepen.io/jonathanrbowman/pen/GgjRoz

HTML

```
<div class="box animate">
  <div class="inner-box animate"></div>
  <div class="line animate"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 6px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.filled-box {
  background-color: green;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -55px;
  margin-left: -55px;
}

.inner-box-collapsed {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.line {
  width: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.line-extended {
  width: 55px;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s; 
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".box").click(function(){
  $(".line").toggleClass("line-extended");
  $(".box").toggleClass("filled-box");
  $(".inner-box").toggleClass("inner-box-collapsed");
});
```

Comment: @Sean actually says that he would like to avoid CSS transitions.

Comment: Understood, I just wanted to make sure that this way absolutely wouldn't work for his situation, given its simplicity. It may not be quite the way he'd like it to work, but if he hasn't tried it this way I thought it might be helpful to see it as a potential option.

Comment: The example was simplified for sake of the question. You can see the more complex usage in the CodePen URL provided via the URL. :)

Comment: I see, my mistake then. I looked at the codepen you provided and thought maybe the different animations could be separated into their own element/transition sets and bound together by jQuery inside the checkbox element. More HTML to write that way, but could still be simpler.

Comment: Certainly not a terrible idea! I liked your second example, but I agree it's a lot more complex, but I'll give you points for effort. :)

Comment: Haha, yea the CSS is certainly more involved to get the multiple animations you are going for, but it has decent compatibility and animates smoothly, with mid-animation reversing not being any issue. And, really, the CSS rules I used are pretty simple ones. I don't know much about the whole key framing side of CSS (looks like it gets complicated real fast!), but hopefully I was able to give you at least a little additional insight into how to achieve your effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, CSS Animations cannot be (properly) manipulated in the way that you need it. It is possibly to get the approximate value of the current keyframe in JavaScript and then dynamically create a new set of key frames that is assigned to your element. For an example, please check out the "Manipulating CSS Animations" section of this article: http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Alternatively, since you will not get around using Javascript anyway, you might want to consider using jQuery (plus jQuery UI to animate `backgroundColor`) for this animation. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3n3zqpa/).